# cannot retrieve value from $_POST

Tags: php

$_POST[$key] does not return a value in my code.var_dump($_POST) gives the correct result.
When i try  echo $_POST[$key], it does not print anything. I'm using mamp; I read the previous post about the similar problem but no solution. Here is my code...
`

```
session_start();    

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $key => $qty){         
        if($_POST[$key] == '0'){
            unset($_SESSION["cart"][$key]);
        }
        else            
            $_SESSION["cart"][$key] = $_POST[$key];
        echo $_POST[$key];  
    }
    var_dump($_POST);
}

$cart = $_SESSION["cart"];
```

?>

```
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <form action="<? echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
    <?  
        if($cart)
        {
    ?>
            <th>Item</th><th>Size</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Unit Price</th><th>Item Subtotal</th>
    <?
            $keys = array_keys($cart);

            foreach($keys as $key) 
            { 
                echo $key;
                $array = explode(".", $key);
                $name = $array[0];
                $size = $array[1];

                $quantity = $cart["$key"];
                echo $quantity;
                $price = $xml->xpath("//item[@name='$name']/price[@size='$size']");
                $unitPrice = (float) $price[0];

                $itemSubtotal = $unitPrice * $quantity;

                $total = $total + $itemSubtotal;
    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><? print($name); ?></td>
                    <td><? print($size); ?></td>
                    <?  ?>
                    <td align="right"><input type = "text" name="<?print($key)?>" value="<? print($quantity); ?>" size="3"/></td>
                    <td align="right">$<? printf("%0.2f", $unitPrice); ?></td>
                    <td align="right">$<? printf("%0.2f", $itemSubtotal); ?></td>
                </tr>
    <?      
            }
    ?>
            <tr><td colspan="5" align="right"><b>Total: $<? printf("%0.2f", $total); ?></b></td></tr>
    <?
        }
        else
        {
    ?>
            Your cart is empty!
    <?  }  ?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update" />
</form>
    </table>

    <p><a href="checkout.php">Checkout</a></p>
```

`

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the output you got or the result of var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `echo` where you want? You're not using brackets in your else statement so only `$_SESSION["cart"][$key] = $_POST[$key];` get executed in that scenario, while the `echo` statement runs in both `if` and `else`.

Comment: The most obvious thing wrong with your code is that you've not trimmed it down to the minimum necessary to replicate the issue. Nor have you provided a var dump of the post.

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro:i'm just using $_POST[$key] to see whether it is printing any value or not. Just for debugging purpose.

Comment: @symcbean: how do i trim it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would be great if you can post the output you are getting.

Also I think you need to loop through `$_POST`, not `$_SESSION["cart"]`

`foreach($_POST as $key => $qty){`

Comment: Did you tried changing `$_SESSION['cart']` to `$_POST` in the `foreach`?

Comment: the output of var_dump($_POST) is "array(2) { ["submit"]=> string(6) "update" ["Three_Aces_Special_small"]=> string(1) "1" } and output of $key is "Three Aces Special.small "

Comment: and what is the output of `echo $_POST[$key];`? It has to be 1.

Comment: using "foreach($_POST as $key => $qty){" gives me the correct output but in my case i don't need to loop through $_POST. The value of my $key "Three Aces Special.small " is not matching with '["Three_Aces_Special_small"]=> string(1) "1" }'.

Comment: Why don't you need to loop through $_POST? You are expecting more keys from form and there will be multiple values. right? I don't think you have to loop through $_SESSION["cart"], because it won't be set on the first run.

Comment: And your question is `When i try echo $_POST[$key], it does not print anything.`, because $_SESSION["cart"] won't contain any values on the submit. Its the answer to your question.. :-)

Comment: $_POST($key) is not giving me any output.

Comment: There are items in the $_session['cart'].I come to cart.php page after adding items into the cart and i've update button to change the value of the quantity.

Comment: Please do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` before the for loop to find what is in session.

Comment: i found the problem, the ' ' and '.' in my $key is replaced with '_' in the $_post. How do i convert it back to ' ' and '.';

Comment: I am not sure, you can do it, because you have replaced two entities to one. And you can't revert it back, as you won't be sure which entity is replaced to underscore. Better keep key in a unique format. Either replace space and period to underscore in session creating part also or remove the replacing script in the form printing section. Anyway I can't find anything replacing script in the code you pasted. Please try to debug yourself.

Comment: the output of var_dump($_SESSION) is "array(1) { ["cart"]=> array(1) { ["Three Aces Special.small"]=> int(1) } } "

Comment: Replace the space and period in key in session. `$key = preg_replace('/\.|\s+/', '_', $key);` will do.